# can we connect my Java-Spring-mvc service to IBM MQ without generating or using binding files from the queues

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8, ibm-mq

in my service(built on java8 - springMVC - IBM MQ) we are generating binding file from IBM MQ and and using that binding file to connect to queues and my service. is there any way i could connect with the queue without using that binding file.

The reason is my service is talking with 10 queues and for every queue i have to generate binding file and put them all in one file and use it and we have dev, qa, prod environments so binding files change for each of them and this is big pain.

so is there a way to connect queues without the binding files and possible please attach the code or any reference!

Comment: whenn you're talking about binding file I guess you are using JNDI ? You didn't mention whether you're using JMS or the native MQI. With MQI you can use connx and with JMS you can use a connection factory to achieve what you want. The developer section in the IBM knowledge center has all information that you need.

Comment: do you have any reference of code that uses JMS ans connects to queue in order to send and receive messages from queue via spring MVC service

Comment: none that I can share... but it's really just one google away... https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jms

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use below code with IBM MQ jars.




import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;
import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQGetMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            MQEnvironment.hostname = queue_manager_ip;
            MQEnvironment.port = queue_manager_port;
            MQEnvironment.channel = channel_name;
            MQEnvironment.disableTracing();

            MQQueueManager mqmanager = null;
            MQQueue mqueue = null;

            try {
                mqmanager = new MQQueueManager(" ");
                int i = 8226;

                mqueue = mqmanager.accessQueue(queue_name, i);
            } catch (MQException localMQException) {
                System.out.println(localMQException.getMessage());
            }
            String str1 = "";
            String str2 = "";

            MQGetMessageOptions localMQGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            localMQGetMessageOptions.options = 8192;

            MQMessage localMQMessage = new MQMessage();
            mqueue.get(localMQMessage, localMQGetMessageOptions);
            byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[localMQMessage.getTotalMessageLength()];
            localMQMessage.readFully(arrayOfByte);
            str1 = new String(arrayOfByte);
            System.out.println(str1);
    }

}
```

Comment: The original poster (OP) of the question mentioned binding file. This would indicate they are using IBM MQ classes for JMS.  I noticed the OP commented asking specifically for "code that uses JMS ... via spring MVC service". While the program you provided may be helpful for another question,  it is a IBM MQ classes for Java program and likely will not be what the OP is looking for.  To have the best chance of getting votes and accepts to gain rep try and tailor the answer to what the OP is looking for.   Sometimes this might require some inferences  if they don't know exactly what to ask for.